# How do I store HTML 5 Geolocation Data on Google App Engine?

Tags: javascript, python, geolocation, google-app-engine-python

I'm working on a web app where users can make posts and can only see posts from others in their vicinity. How I envision this to work is:

Request Geolocation data from user --> Store user's Geolocation data in file on server --> Check the file if any other coordinates stored are within a certain range of the latitude/longitude of the user's --> Display only posts within range

How would I go about storing the user's latitude and longitude data? The back end of the GAE site is in Python, if that's important.

Comment: What did you try? You should always first try something out.

Comment: I can store the coordinates to a JSON file but I have no idea how the end user can check the server side for other coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is very helpful, and lists a [`GeoPtProperty`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Types) which does exactly what you want.